# pandas adding grouped data frame to another data frame as row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get following dataframe:

```
category_name             amount
Blades & Razors & Foam     158
Diaper                     486
Empty                      193
Fem Care                  2755
HairCare                  3490
Irrelevant                1458
Laundry                    889
Oral Care                 2921
Others                      69
Personal Cleaning Care    1543
Skin Care                  645
```

I want to add it as row to following dataframe that has additional `retailer column` that is absent with the first dataframe.

```
categories_columns = ['retailer'] + self.product_list.category_name.unique().tolist()
categories_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=categories_columns)
```

And if some category is missing I just want zero value.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `set_index` to move the `category_name` column into the index. Then taking the transpose (`.T`) will move the `category_name`s into the column index:

```
In [35]: df1
Out[35]: 
   amount cat
0       0   A
1       1   B
2       2   C

In [36]: df1.set_index('cat').T
Out[36]: 
cat     A  B  C
amount  0  1  2
```

Once the category names (`cat`, above) are in the column index, you can concatenate 
the reshaped DataFrame with the second DataFrame using `append` or `pd.concat.

`pd.concat` fills missing values with `NaN`. Use `fillna(0)` to replace the `NaN`s with 0.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'amount': range(3), 'cat': list('ABC')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2*4).reshape(2, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
result = df2.(df1.set_index('cat').T).fillna(0)
print(result)
```

yields

```
        A  B  C    D
0       0  1  2  3.0
1       4  5  6  7.0
amount  0  1  2  0.0
```

Comment: if I have with df2 column 'retailer' , how I can fill it on insert ?

Answer (score 0):

Just append and replace Nan :

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=products).append(df.T).fillna(0)
```